# Feature Selection Phase

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I am trying to predict the overall age of an opportunity (creation date - closing date) this is my response variable

lets say an opportunity  passes through 3 stages
to close

For example: Opp x stayed in

- stage 1 : 30 days
- stage 2 : 10 days
- stage 3:  20 days

At stage 3 I might close it same date or wait some time

so if I waited some time to close, it will be createdon: 22/11/2018 & closedon:9/2/2019

There is opp y , where i close it in same date of stage 3, so createdon:22/11/2018 and closedate: 21/1/2019

Summary

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| OppName | oppAge | stage1 | stage2 | stage3 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| x       |     79 |     30 |     10 |     20 |
| y       |     60 |     30 |     10 |     20 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

my question is :

1. Can I include stage1,2,3 as my independent variables to create a regression model?
2. They seem to nearly make the model ideal, so is it better to include maybe only stage 1? without 2 &3

### Work Done ,Added Edits

- I transformed stages to a categorical nature, for example <30 days to 1 month
  30-60 day transformed it to 1-2months and so on

  ```
   +-----------+
  |  stage1   |
  +-----------+
  | <1month   |
  | 1~2months |
  | 6~7months |
  +-----------+
  ```
- Then I did one-hot encode to the stages like stage 1
- Then I stopped ,wasn't sure whether to include everything or what?

Answer (score 0):

One-hot encode those three *Stage* variables instead of including all three of them. And again, include any of those at all, ONLY if they hold relevance so a pre-hand PCA won't be a bad idea overall.

Comment: why to one-hot encode my stages if they are already numerical?  Are you saying to apply PCA OR to include only stage1 and 2 ?

Comment: Noticed your edits! Instead of renaming them to something _categorical_ like `<1month`, rename it to something like `0` for your `<1 month` category, `1` for `1~2months` category, and so on. PCA not really required now.

Comment: Okay so after renaming them, lets say I include all the dummy variables(from onehot encode) that was created for stage 1 and stage 2, then drop stage 3, correct?

Comment: Yes, then drop any one of those columns to avoid multi-colinearity.